# how to convert text to number in a SOQL query?

Tags: socrata, soda

Can somebody please help me figure out what is wrong with this query?

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/i4gi-tjb9.json?$where=speed<10

It failed with error code: query.soql.type-mismatch

the "speed" column of the table is declared as text. I am having trouble in converting speed to a real (decimal) number for the comparison. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the column with `::number`, like this:

```
GET https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/i4gi-tjb9.json?$where=speed::number > 31.69
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the number in parenthesis, like this:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/i4gi-tjb9.json?$where=speed<"10"

or if you need it url encoded, use this:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/i4gi-tjb9.json?$where=speed%3C%2210%22